# Node.js Error: connect ECONNREFUSED when using http.request

Tags: node.js

I am troubleshooting a Node.js script, and have stripped out almost all of the code and still am able to reproduce the following error:

```
{ 
  [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 
          at exports._errnoException (util.js:682:11) 
          at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:947:19)',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' 
}
```

The entire script is:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php", function(res) {
    console.log("Received response: " + res.statusCode);
});

var req = http.request(function(res) {
    console.log("Request began");
    var output = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        output += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Request complete:');
        console.log(output);
    });
});

req.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    //console.log('error: ' + err.message);
});

req.end();
console.log("Script complete");
```

I'm confident this is a simple mistake somewhere in the code, but have been unable to identify the problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't provided a url in `http.request`.

Try `var req = http.request("someurlhere", function(res) {` ... etc.

Moreover, if you're using http.request like that, I can't quite see the purpose of the following block of code at all (maybe remnants from the rest of the completed script?)

```
http.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php", function(res) {
    console.log("Received response: " + res.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: Ah! Blast it your right, adding it like this works `var req = http.request("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php", function(res) {`

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple mistake. I cant accept your answer yet it says still 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

This question became popular, so I want to point you on a popular NodeJS library that make requesting much eaiser.

This is my choice because it's using same syntax as `fetch` browsers api. So learing same syntax always better.

It's also uses the new promises syntax, so you can use `async/await`

```
var fetch=require('node-fetch')
var data=await fetch(url);
var text=await data.text()
```

### Learn more:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: And as of Node 18, you don't need a third party library. The Fetc API is now natively supported.