# PHP Built-in (CLI) webserver dies without error

Tags: php

Here is the background:

I have a php api providing back-end data to an angular app.  I have set up a "sandbox" api for use in protractor e2e tests in the angular app.  This runs the real api code with fake fixture data like this:

```
//open test server
$command = sprintf("APPLICATION_ENV=sandbox php -S 127.0.0.1:%d -t %s", $port, $public);
print "\nRunning API sandbox on port $port\n";
$process = popen($command, 'r');
```

My problem is that if I run my entire suite of protractor tests, at some point, the php cli webserver will just die.  If I run all the tests independently, they all will pass.  The webserver failure looks like this:

```
[Mon Nov 17 15:44:54 2014] 127.0.0.1:58641 [200]: /some/route/1
[Mon Nov 17 15:44:54 2014] 127.0.0.1:58644 [201]: /some/route/2
[Mon Nov 17 15:44:54 2014] 127.0.0.1:58647 [201]: /some/route/3
[Mon Nov 17 15:44:54 2014] Invalid argument
```

The lack of a backend obviously causes my protractor tests to die:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Does anybody have any ideas for tracking down this problem?  The protractor + sandbox api setup is awesome but I just can't get it to run as a whole unit (note, this has worked for me in other projects).  There is no error output, no response, nothing in logs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: some questions/clues where to look for: the error is consistent and reproducible? do you have enough memory and space? do you do any kind of read/write of files? if you use some library, are all internal requirements satisfied?

Comment: sounds more like a node.js error than a PHP one. check this one: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6215

Comment: and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488496/node-js-error-connect-econnrefused-when-using-http-request

Comment: This is a PHP built-in server error because I'm having it if I run PHP server from shell directly. I guess it's hitting some system limit, maybe some file descriptors or smt. because it fails after serving some number of requests.

Comment: Do you have access to the php error log?. I know it sounds way too easy but maybe you can detect some stuff that makes php die or silently fail (memory problems? too many post parameters?, etc...).

Comment: Hey, I have exactly the same problem, have you managed to find a solution? On OS X it gives the same line as you have, on Linux there is also a Segmentation Fault. Tried it on several systems. Nothing seems to work after several requests (>100 probably) it just dies.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you show me your segfault log from Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I've disabled Xdebug and working fine now.